# call a function in one application from another application in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, cross-domain

I have an angular application hosted in domain `a.com` which contain a `template.ts` file containing a function

`list(ids :any){
     alert(JSON.stringify(ids));
 }`

I need to call this `list` function in `a.com` from domain `b.com` which contain a `custom.js` file containing a function

```
function getIds(){ }
```

in any way is it possible to call a function in one domain from another. Like if we add `allow origin` header or something.

Answer (score 0):

> since every application works in a strictly sand boxed environment
>   there is no way you can communicate across multiple domains with in
>   the browser in fact you can't even communicate the same application
>   one running in `http://localhost` (which refers to http://127.0.0.1)
>   and `http://127.0.0.1`.

The only way you can achieve this is externalizing the the data you want in an API (some thing like REST) and fetching it in the predecessor.